# Why cannot I join any Stack Exchange community as for now?

Tags: support, login, user-accounts

https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/

I tried to join this astronomy community using the button on the top right. However, it tells me that "You cannot register at this time.

If you continue to find this error, contact us." I also tried to click on the log in button just below this message, but it doesn't work either.

Later I tried to join other communities, but neither will let me in. How can I solve that? May it be because that I haven't logged in for some time?

Comment: How are you trying to sign up?

Comment: What browser? What version? On what platform (incl. "edition" (if any) / version)? Desktop / mobile?

Comment: Google chrome browser, on my mac.